# Python equivalent for matlab Preconditioned Conjugate Gradients Method on function handle

Tags: python, matlab, gradient-descent

Is there an equivalent Python expression for the following Preconditioned Conjugate Gradients Method in Matlab, where the first argument is a function handle and not a matrix :

```
pcg(@(x)myfunction(x,arg1, arg2),x0,thres,max_iter);
```

Comment: you may need to write it yourself, its not a hard algorithm

Comment: I haven't found something similar to a function handle in python

Comment: Oh, then you searched very little! They are called Lambda functions. Still, if you write your own `PGC` then you do not need to use Lambdas, you can just replace the matrix multiplications `A*x` by your function

Comment: I had the impression that you can pass a single argument function using lambda expressions and linear operators (and not arg1, arg2 as well), but I'll look into it further. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can combine [`scipy.sparse.linalg.cg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.cg.html) with [`scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html).

"Many iterative methods (e.g. cg, gmres) do not need to know the individual entries of a matrix to solve a linear system A*x=b. Such solvers only require the computation of matrix vector products, A*v where v is a dense vector. This class serves as an abstract interface between iterative solvers and matrix-like objects."

"M : {sparse matrix, dense matrix, LinearOperator}
Preconditioner for A. The preconditioner should approximate the inverse of A. Effective preconditioning dramatically improves the rate of convergence, which implies that fewer iterations are needed to reach a given error tolerance."